# How can I extract only date from a string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I search before ask, but I what I've tested doesn't work. I have following string:

```
2016-07-31 00:32:29 debian-8gb-sfo2-01 gamed: notice :
```

I want to know how can I extract date from this string. The full regex (missing the date regex) returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-07-31 00:32:29 debian-8gb-sfo2-01 gamed: notice : formatlog:gshop_trade:userid=1792:db_magic_number=1744:order_id=23727:item_id=47494:expire=0:item_count=1:cash_need=1:cash_left=99976272:guid1=0:guid2=0
    [1] => 2016-07-31 00:32:29 debian-8gb-sfo2-01 gamed: notice :
    [2] => 1792
    [3] => db_magic_number=1744:order_id=23727:
    [4] => 47494
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 99976272
)
```

It's correct, but the desire output is:

```
Array 
(
        [1] => 2016-07-31 00:32:29
        [2] => 1792
        [3] => db_magic_number=1744:order_id=23727:
        [4] => 47494
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 1
        [7] => 1
        [8] => 99976272
)
```

The current code:

```
if (strpos($line, 'gshop_trade:userid=1792:') > 0) {
    if (!preg_match('/(.*)\sformatlog:gshop_trade:userid=(\d+):(.*)item_id=(\d+):expire=(\d+):item_count=(\d+):cash_need=(\d+):cash_left=(\d+).*$/', $line, $d)) {
        // error occured
    }
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($d);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the regex you're using? You make mention of it, but don't display it.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the code used to extract the date. Judging by your data, you add group 0 to the output.

Comment: @Seth I added the code.

Comment: You didn't capture date time separately at all: `/\s*(\S+\s+\S+).*\sformatlog:gshop_trade:userid=(\d+):(.*)item_id=(\d+):expire=(\d+):item_count=(\d+):cash_need=(\d+):cash_left=(\d+).*$\K/`

Comment: What about using [`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\b([^\W\d]+)\s*=\s*\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/djf6yW/2)?

Comment: @ctwheels Because I don't have just this struct to read, I have many others, with this one above I can change to match what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/([\d-: ]+)\s.*\sformatlog:gshop_trade:userid=(\d+):(.*)item_id=(\d+):expire=(\d+):item_count=(\d+):cash_need=(\d+):cash_left=(\d+).*$/
```

You were using a capture group around items that you didn't wish to capture at the start, the group `([\d-: ]+)` should capture the date correctly

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfJtje/1)

Comment: Yup! Work perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you want to match exactly the date from any string in the format YYYY-MM-DD use the below Regular expression

**[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}**